# Flutter CLI not able to install

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, command-line-interface

When trying to install the CLI I get this message:

The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.5.

Because pub global activate depends on flutterfire_cli any which requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

this is what I get when running flutter doctor -v:

Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                       4,2s
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.4.0-19.0.pre.86, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
• Flutter version 3.4.0-19.0.pre.86 on channel master at /Users/rimaasri/Development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision a04e6b7618 (2 hours ago), 2022-09-06 02:08:10 -0400
• Engine revision 623b80157c
• Dart version 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-171.0.dev)
• DevTools version 2.17.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/rimaasri/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 13F100
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.0)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.48.0

I can't find the problem because I thing I have the newest version of dart....

Comment: hey, were you able to solve this? if so can you please post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it with:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade --force
```

then cleaning the workspace again with:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```